# Ambiguous result shows in count(1) in documentdb query Explorer

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a collection with 90,000 records and each and every time,data is added onto it. But whenever I query 'select count(c.id) from c'. It will shows ambiguous result sometimes 20,190 or 19,916 or 22,897 like that, It won't able to give the exact output.

```
[
  {
    "$1": 21687
  }
]
```

Comment: Are you executing the `COUNT` aggregation via code or in the portal? Important distinction.

Comment: Both via Python code and the portal

Comment: Ambiguous result shows in aggregate function count in documentdb query Explorer in a huge dataset fro more than 10 lakh records or more

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely that the query cannot finish in one shot. 20,000 is roughly the batch size we experience. To confirm this, look for a continuation token in the response headers. If there, you'll need to resubmit with that token until it comes back without a continuation token and sum all the counts from call-side.

Comment: Is that any solution to count total number of records without traversing the whole documents?

Comment: Unfortunately no